# Group by months and get their counts in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document with the following structure.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "review_id" : "1",
    "product_id" : "1",
    "date" : 1638869377,
    "rating" : 5,
    "title" : "lorem",
    "review" : "lorem",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-12-07T07:10:55.732Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-12-07T05:04:11.750Z")
}
```

I managed to get the number of user comments by month. But I want to get it separately for each rating.

For example, in the 10th month there are 7 comments and how can I get 2 of them 1 star, 3 of them 4 stars, 2 of them 5 stars?

```
 {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "month": {
        "$month": {
          "$toDate": "$date"
        }
      }
    },
    "reviews": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Field `date` is a `Date` value. It is useless to run `$toDate` on a value which is already a `Date`

Comment: Yes it is. Actually, I keep it as a unix timestamp and then I converted it to a date object, so I missed it. I'm fixing it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add everything you want to group by inside the `_id` field. Just adding a new field with the rating would do the job.

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "month": {
        "$month": {
          "$toDate": "$date"
        }
      },
      "rating": "$rating"
    },
    "reviews": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I would also add a group by year, so you can get each month separed properly. If you dont add them, Mongo will group every January of every year together for example.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iBBNs-FxM-Q)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to `$group` by both fields, the `month` and the `rating`, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "month": {
          "$month": {
            "$toDate": "$date"
          }
        },
        rating: "$rating"
      },
      "reviews": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NCPOkfH4F1a)

Or my recommendation just to add a little more structuring to the output is to use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cyRxtz3FzCV) pipeline.